# Finding modules on python

Tags: python, idle-python

Python can't find my modules on the IDE but can find it from the terminal. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Terminal:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>>
```

Python IDE:

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
  import matplotlib
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Comment: Do you have more than one version of python installed?  You IDE is probably using a different version of python fro your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are using `python2` on the command line and `python3` in the ide, try installing `matplotlib` in both enviroments.

```
apt-get install python-matplotlib python3-matplotlib
```